# reactive class getter without state or props update reactjs

Tags: reactjs, eventsource

I am trying to implement a live badge — whether the current data is up-to-date. [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) is used to get data from the backend.

Up-to-date state is calculated like that: each time I get new data from EventSource, I update `state.timestamp` to current timestamp; then in `isLive` getter I check that between current time and saved timestamp has passed less than 5 seconds.

In the case of API stopped responding (e.g. is down), new data isn't coming, so the state isn't updating, and `render` function isn't being called.

Finally, I get `live: true` when should get `live: false`. How should I fix this issue?

```
import React from "react";

const MAX_DELAY_IN_MS = 5 * 1000;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // creating an instance of EventSource
    const source = new EventSource("...");

    // binding event listeners
    this.onMessage = this._onMessage.bind(this);
    source.addEventListener("message", this.onMessage);

    this.state = {
      source,

      data: [],
      timestamp: null
    };
  }

  /**
   * Checks that between current time and last response time
   * has passed less than MAX_DELAY_IN_MS milliseconds.
   *
   * @property {boolean} isLive
   */
  get isLive() {
    const { timestamp } = this.state;

    return Date.UTC() - timestamp < MAX_DELAY_IN_MS;
  }

  _onMessage(event) {
    const { data } = this.state;

    // saving new data + setting new timestamp
    this.setState({
      data: [...data, event.data],
      timestamp: Date.UTC()
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {/* always shows "true", even if the backend stopped responding */}
        {/* i guess that is because state/props aren't updated, so render() isn't called */}
        <p>Live: {this.isLive ? "true" : "false"}</p>

        {data.map(item => (
          <div key={item}>{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { source } = this.state;

    source.removeEventListener("message", this.onMessage);
    source.close();
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** I made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cloud-dh535?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) project for testing this issue. `EventSource` is replaced with `FakeEventSource` that emits data every 500 ms. You can imitate that API is down by pressing the corresponding button `Imitate when Backend API is Down`.